# 'OrderItem' object has no attribute 'Product'

Tags: python, django, django-models

app is runing good but when i try to add some items into add item through admin panel then I got this error meanwhile I have add product in my model.

error says:
AttributeError at /admin/store/orderitem/add/
'OrderItem' object has no attribute 'Product'

code of add item model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Product.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you write `Product` with a capital P in `__str__`, while it has a lowercase p in the `OrderItem` class

Comment: @ZohaibUlHassan if it really helped you then, mark this answer as accepted and consider upvoting it..